# I'm thinking of completely uninstalling Windows 10 and using Elementary OS full time but I have a couple questions

Tags: graphic-drivers, microsoft-windows

Will the Fn function keys be able to work fully?

Also, I have a full 1080p HD display but its a bit peculiar. The screen will dim and brighten on dark/white backgrounds. I disabled this so it functions normally using Intel's Graphic Properties.

Will I still be able to fix this in elementary OS if the screen reverts to its old habits?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange · Would you please break separate questions into separate pages? We try to keep one page per question so as to make the answers useful for future searchers

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to your specific issues, but Windows driver issues made me switch to elementary OS.  I went from several major, unresolvable issues to just a few minor annoyances without needing to do anything special.

Before uninstalling Windows, put elementary on a thumb drive and try it out in Live CD mode.  It will run slower than when natively installed, but you can test the environment first.  Here's the support page if you need more info (you don't have to only use Rufus):

https://elementary.io/docs/installation#install-on-windows

While elementary runs fine out of the box, you'll find it takes more tinkering than Windows to get everything looking and working how you prefer.  But that's kinda the point -- you can do a lot of customizing.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes, the fn functionality is controlled by the keyboard and can be tweaked in the BIOS settings.

try this the next time you start up your computer: press the power button, spam the esc key until it says something like: "Esc...pausing boot", then select BIOS settings and use your arrow keys (or on some newer system the BIOS supports mouse)to search for "action keys" this should give you a more detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific issues on Igfx products make sure to look well within their fora. They have an unofficial development of the Linux driver for their products that i used - at least until fedora 22 - But Fedora - most likely because of the Fedora policy against any 3rd party involvement - they were always running late. I have no experience with this as far as "Ubuntu bases" distributions. I have to say that their efforts did improve the performance quite a bit.